# Make a copy of object to use later

Tags: delphi, object

I have a component with the following class:

```
TResp=Class
...

TRespostasPendentes = class(TObjectList)
   private
      fSaldoAPagar : Double;
      function GetSaldoRestante : Double;
      function GetTotalPago : Double;
      function GetTotalDesconto : Double;
   protected
      procedure SetObject (Index: Integer; Item: TResp);
      function GetObject (Index: Integer): TResp;
   public
      function Add (Obj: TResp): Integer;
      procedure Insert (Index: Integer; Obj: TResp);
      property Objects [Index: Integer]: TResp
        read GetObject write SetObject; default;

      property SaldoAPagar   : Double read fSaldoAPagar write fSaldoAPagar ;
      property TotalPago     : Double read GetTotalPago ;
      property TotalDesconto : Double read GetTotalDesconto ;
      property SaldoRestante : Double read GetSaldoRestante ;
   end;
```

I need to make a copy of the objects in a `TRespostasPendentes` to use later after it is freed.

The original class does not implement the `Assign()` method.

I tried the next code, but I get an Access Violation when freeing the copy.

What am I doing wrong?

I can't change the original class.

```
RespostasPendentes:=TRespostasPendentes.Create;
//Here I fill some properties of RespostasPendentes
RP:=TRespostasPendentes.Create;
try
  RP.Assign(RespostasPendentes);
  RespostasPendentes.Free; 
finally
  RP.Free; -->Access Violation
end;
```

Comment: Well, make that class' descendant which will implement `Assign` method then.

Comment: The class descend of TObjectList and It has assign method, but TrespostasPendentes doesnt have your owner assign.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to make a copy to use later, instead of just keeping the original one around or creating it again when needed?

Comment: Hi, Mr Ken. I need to make a copy because the third component is destroied before I execute a procedure in my app using it. My app has no control to stop the component to destroy before I can use it.

Comment: "I tried the next but I get an access violation when free the copy. What am I doing wrong?" One thing you appear to be doing wrong is not debugging the code, it would seem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`TObjectList.OwnsObjects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList.OwnsObjects) property is True by default. `TObjectList` [inherits `Assign()` from `TList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TList.Assign), which by default simply copies pointers from the source list.

So, you end up with two `TObjectList` objects that both "own" the same set of objects, and thus you get an AV when one list tries to free the same objects that the other list has already freed.

To prevent the 1st list from freeing the objects, you need to either:

- set the 1st list's `OwnsObjects` to False after copying the object pointers to the 2nd list.

  ```
  RespostasPendentes := TRespostasPendentes.Create;
  // ...
  RP := TRespostasPendentes.Create(False); // <-- False initially in case Assign() fails...
  try
    RP.Assign(RespostasPendentes);
    RespostasPendentes.OwnsObjects := False; // <-- add this 
    RP.OwnsObjects := True; // <-- take ownership of the copied pointers
    RespostasPendentes.Free; 
    // use RP as needed...
  finally
    RP.Free;
  end;
  ```
- [`Extract()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Extract) the object pointers from the 1st list to make it relinquish ownership without freeing the objects, and then add the pointers to the 2nd list.

  ```
  RespostasPendentes := TRespostasPendentes.Create;
  // ...
  RP := TRespostasPendentes.Create;
  try
    RP.Capacity := RespostasPendentes.Count;
    while RespostasPendentes.Count > 0 do
    begin
      Obj := RespostasPendentes.Objects[0];
      RespostasPendentes.Extract(Obj); // <-- remove ownership
      try
        RP.Add(Obj); // <-- take ownership
      except
        Obj.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
    RespostasPendentes.Free; 
    // use RP as needed...
  finally
    RP.Free;
  end;
  ```

Comment: If this is the case, the supposed reproduction case conveniently does not reproduce the problem since there are no objects/items.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz "*Here I fill some properties of RespostasPendentes*" - I take that as creating objects without showing the code for it

Comment: @Remy, correct me if I'm wrong, for you to use Extract(), the OwnsObjects needs to be set to false, because Extract() does not free the extracted element if OwnsObjects is True

Comment: Thank  you Remy. That was it

Comment: @Fero Regardless of what `OwnsObjects` is set to, `Extract()` always relinquishes ownership of the pointer *without* freeing the object being pointed at. [This is documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Extract). My example depends on that behavior, extracting objects without freeing them so they can be moved to the other list.